# Adding multiple HTML form input values in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am bewildered as to why I cannot add three numbers together.  Here is my HTML:

```
<div><label>Sales Price: </label>
    <input type="number" name="sales_price" value="3">
</div>
<div><label>Incentives: </label>
    <input type="number" name="incentives" value="2">
</div>    
<div><label>Acquisition Fee: </label>
    <input type="number" name="acq_fee" value="1">
```

Here is my JavaScript:

```
var salesPrice = document.getElementsByName("sales_price")[0];
var incentives = document.getElementsByName("incentives")[0];
var acqFee = document.getElementsByName("acq_fee")[0];

var netCapCost = salesPrice.value - incentives.value + acqFee.value;
```

I wanted a simple calculation to be done: (3-2+1) = 2.  However, `netCapCost` returns 11, which is the concatenation of the result of (3-2) and 1.  What did I do wrong? Many Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var salesPrice;
var incentives;
var acqFee;
var npc;


function calculate(e) {
    var netCapCost = (parseFloat(salesPrice.value) - parseFloat(incentives.value) + parseFloat(acqFee.value)).toPrecision(3);
    npc.value = netCapCost;
}

window.onload = function (){
 
 
salesPrice = document.getElementsByName("sales_price")[0];
incentives = document.getElementsByName("incentives")[0];
acqFee = document.getElementsByName("acq_fee")[0];
npc = document.getElementsByName("npc")[0];
 salesPrice.onchange = calculate;
 calculate();
 
 
};
```

Your problem is that text fields value is always of type STRING. When subtracting it forces a conversion to type FLOAT. Then the plus operation shares an opperator with the concatenate operation. So when you have two strings being added it concatenates rather than converting to FLOAT or INT. So basically you have "2"-"1" being converted to 2-1 as strings cannot be subtracted which gives you (1) then you have (1)+"1" which will concatenate rather than add as you have a string. Always use parseFloat or parseInt when expecting numeric data from user entry as it will always be a string when originally submitted.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I tried using your code but it returned no answer.  I tried `parseFloat(document.getElementsByName("sales_price")[0].value)` as well, since I want to convert the value to a number, but it didn't seem to work either.  https://jsfiddle.net/mademoiselletse/uge2qzqv/1/

Comment: I have altered my code above. Works in my normal browser but not in JSFiddle as it uses the window.load event. I accidently applied parseFloat to the element object rather than the value.

Comment: @Vic removed onLoad from jsfiddle. here you go. https://jsfiddle.net/pcconsolidated/c39ge74z/2/

Comment: Just t is food practice to use the onload event to ensure the body is loaded before assigning elements to the variables or it could try to assign it before the element is created.

Comment: thank you so much!  It works!  May I ask why assigning `var salesPrice = parseFloat(document.getElementsByName("sales_price")[0].value)` would not work?

Comment: It would work. However you assigned salesPrice = parseFloat(document.getElementsByName("sales_price")[0]). Which i figured it would be better to assign salesPrice = document.getElementsByName("sales_price")[0] so that it would remain bound to the text box. If you called salesPrice = parseFloat(document.getElementsByName("sales_price")[0].value) and the value changes you will have to reasign the value rather than being able to call parseFloat(salesPrice.Value)

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert those values into numbers with `parseInt()` or else the `+` operator will be interpreted as string concatenation. You are doing

```
var netCapCost = salesPrice.value - incentives.value + acqFee.value;
```

Which is

```
var netCapCost = "3" - "2" + "1"
```

`"3"-"2"` will return 1, which is what you want but `1 + "1"` will be concatenated into `"11"` since the right operand is a string. So Number + String -> concatenation

Comment: i don't believe parseInt will be the correct way to go as the price could be (5.95). I believe parseFloat is the better approach

Answer (score 1):

you are doing a string concatation, all value get from input value are string,

the first calcuation `salesPrice.value - incentives.value` is currect is becuase, the `-` sign convert the incentives.value to number

the currect way is

```
var netCapCost = parseInt(salesPrice.value, 10) - parseInt(incentives.value, 10) + parseInt(acqFee.value, 10);
```

it's better to use a Math library to do the calcuation in javascript, because sooner or later, you will encounter the problem like `0.3 - 0.2 = 0.09999999`

Comment: i don't believe parseInt will be the correct way to go as the price could be (5.95). I believe parseFloat is the better approach

Comment: yes, I'm just clearify the main problem in the example code, parseFloat is also not correct when calculate price, as I mentioned, 0.3 - 0.2 !== 0.1

Comment: Alright. I have always done with parseFloat().toPrecision(3);

Answer (score 1):

I think confusion here is HTML 5 introduces input type number however javascript engine doesn't introduce support for reading such specific fields.  We end up using old traditional way of reading input field value which defaults everything to string.

Only advantage of using number type field would be that you do not have to worry about exception/erroneous situation where number is not being entered.

Other answer suggesting to use `parseInt` function, is the way to go unless you have luxury of introducing javascript framework like jQuery and use more sophisticated approach for reading it.

Comment: You still need to worry about validation as many browsers will allow a manual entry of non numbers into number fields.